# TestNG Is it possible to capture screenshot on @BeforeMethod fail?

Tags: testng

There are typical solutions for capturing screenshot while `@Test` failing, but is it possible to do that on `@Before/After` `Class/Method` fail?

Why I need that? - It will be good especially for `@BeforeMethod` where I use common logic for test class - login and go to specific page.

Comment: have you tried to use `Itestresult` like this , `@AfterMethod
 public void takeScreenShotOnFailure(ITestResult testResult) throws IOException {
  if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
   System.out.println(testResult.getStatus());
   File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
   FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\testScreenShot.jpg"));
    }        
 }`  you can use same for @BeforeMethod

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try and implement `WebDriverEventListener` in your case you may be interested in method `onException` which will allow you to do smthn on every exeception that occurs during code execution, also it'll be necessary to use `EventFiringWebDriver` to add listener

Here are some references:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html

Comment: not sure that it related to webdriver. this should be testng related solution.

Answer (score 0):

currently stops on overriding TestNG `ITestListener` - `onTestSkipped` method. cons is that screenshots are taking for each skipped `@Test` method. offcourse, below code should be refactored, but it's a good point to start. note: you should include this custom listener into your testng.xml

```
@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    if(result != null){
        String failedTestScreenshotFolder = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString() + "path/skippedScreenshots/";
        WebDriver webDriver = ((TestBase)result.getInstance()).webDriver;
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            String className = result.getTestClass().getName();
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(failedTestScreenshotFolder + className.substring(className.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + "." + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + ".jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For @Before annotation, you could make a workaround by putting screenshots in **public void onTestSkipped(final ITestResult result)** because when you get any failure in Before methods, all @Test will be skipped and onTestSkipped will be invoked.

That's how I solved it in my project :)